# Using Python logging module, how to filter error level logs from all level log file and store it into file?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

In Python application, I am storing all level of logs(info,warning,error) in a log file using logging module.
I have to filter only error logs from all level log file and store the error logs to a file and then I need upload only error logs file to AWS S3 bucket.

How to filter error logs from all level log file and store the error logs to a file?

My requirement is I should not use two log handlers.

Comment: I think you'd want to utilize two separate handlers. One has a level of DEBUG and writes messages to the log file for all logs.  The other has a level of ERROR and writes messages to the log file you want to upload to AWS S3.

Comment: @saquintes. Thanks for the reply. We can use two handlers. But I want to know is it possible if we have only all logs file and we want to filter only error logs from it and store it to another file?

Comment: Are you saying the "all logs" file already exists and you want to parse it for just the error logs?  The answer to this is intrinsically tied to the format of the log file.  If this is what you want, it might be helpful to provide some example log messages. If you are looking to filter in real time...well...that's the exact use-case for different handlers.